# fortran array undefined address

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fortran, undefined, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am using Visual studio 2008 with intel fortran compiler (10.1.025).

In my program I have a subroutine solvemgmt()

```
subroutine solvemgmt()
use precision
use data_global
use lib_interface
implicit none

integer     :: m           
integer     :: p1          
integer     :: c1          
integer     :: c2          
integer     :: g1          
integer     :: g2          
integer     :: t1          
integer     :: t2          
real(iwp)   :: ptime = 0.0 

real(iwp), allocatable  :: t1xfree(:,:,:) ! *** Break point 1 ***
real(iwp), allocatable  :: t1force(:,:)
real(iwp), allocatable  :: t2xfree(:,:,:)
real(iwp), allocatable  :: t2force(:,:)
real(iwp), allocatable  :: t2f(:,:)
real(iwp), allocatable  :: jfres(:,:)
real(iwp), allocatable  :: intfr(:,:)

m  = gdtratio
p1 = 1
g1 = gpair(p1)%gfid(1)
g2 = gpair(p1)%gfid(2)
t1 = gpair(p1)%tfid(1)
t2 = gpair(p1)%tfid(2)

allocate(t1xfree(0:gparam(t1)%neq,3,m))
allocate(t1force(0:gparam(t1)%neq,0:m))
allocate(t2xfree(0:gparam(t2)%neq,3,m))
allocate(t2force(0:gparam(t2)%neq,0:m))
allocate(t2f(0:gparam(t2)%neq,3))
allocate(jfres(0:gparam(t1)%neq,m))
allocate(intfr(gpair(p1)%lmn*gpair(p1)%lmnodof,m))

:  ! *** Break point 2 ***
:
:

return
end subroutine solvemgmt
```

While debugging, when at break point 1,

```
    T2XFREE  Undefined pointer/array    REAL(8) 
    T2F  Undefined address  REAL(8) 
    INTFR    Undefined address  REAL(8) 
    T2FORCE  Undefined address  REAL(8) 
    JFRES    Undefined address  REAL(8) 
    T1FORCE  Undefined address  REAL(8) 
    T1XFREE  Undefined pointer/array    REAL(8)
```

When at break point 2,

```
    T2XFREE {...}   REAL(8) 
    T2F  Undefined pointer/array    REAL(8) 
    INTFR    Undefined pointer/array    REAL(8) 
    T2FORCE  Undefined pointer/array    REAL(8) 
    JFRES    Undefined pointer/array    REAL(8) 
    T1FORCE  Undefined pointer/array    REAL(8) 
    T1XFREE {...}   REAL(8)
```

I don't understand why T2F,INTFR,T2FORCE,JFRES and T1FORCE show as Undefined address and then as Undefined Pointer/Array.

Comment: That is a rather old version of that compiler.  It could simply be a VS debug integration bug.

Comment: is there a configuration option to avoid such errors?

Comment: If I copy your code and set values explicitly, eg replace `gparam(t1)%neq` by `9`, then the code compiles without a hitch and the debugger shows what you expect at break point 2, the allocatable arrays have been allocated.  But I'm using Intel Fortran 13.1.2 on VS2010, so this may be a version-dependent issue.  I've certainly encountered cases, like yours here, where the VS debugger failed to display values in valid (and working) Fortran code.  I concur with @IanH's conclusion.

Comment: it sure does seem like a debug integration bug. gfortran compiles my code like a charm. I need to upgrade my intel compiler! thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like a debug/release problem.  Are you using the debug version or the release version when you are looking at the values?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.